# How is @ElementCollection stored?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here is part of my User Entity, as you can see, it has Enum Roles

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

The table role is missing, I only have one linking table `user_roles`. How is the data stored if I can't see it? How can I manually change role in PostgreSQL if I can't edit linking table?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The user_roles table will have the id of main table User and the suppose, in list of roles, 5 values are passed, then five rows will be stored in user_roles table.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani thank you for your answer, I can't find anything with Enum values, no table at all. Roles references something but I can't even find what.

Comment: can you share a git hub link to your project ? will be easier to explain then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role information is stored in `user_roles`. It is the nature of `@ElementCollection` which the collection will be mapped to a table which does not have any primary key column and have a FK column reference to its parent (i.e `users`) .

The value in the `user_role` 's roles column is not any role ID that you can find its record in some role master table. It is just the ordinal of the `Role` enum.

If you change it to :

```java
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Role> roles;
```

Then the data in user_role will become :

```
user_id | roles 
----------------
    1   | ADMIN
    1   | DEV
    2   | DEV
    3   | ADMIN
```

where the value in the roles column become the item name of `Role` enum.